# Determine whether a KeyEvent is belongs to KEY_PRESSED type

Tags: java

I am getting an instance of `KeyEvent` from a 3rd party libraries.

How can I know whether the event is a `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` type? Which method from `KeyEvent` I should call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
```